# What does "ground" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

[source](https://people.com/crime/california-flight-school-staffers-tried-deport-chinese-student/)

> Shi told the Record Searchlight that he’d been “**grounded**” for the
>   past two months, restricting his ability or fly or train at the school
>   where students are “required to use English in all their
>   communications to better prepare them for their pilot careers,”
>   according to IASCO’s website.

I looked it up. It maybe means "study the basic knowledge" or "be treated badly (force to the ground)".

What is the real meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See *ground* verb definition #1

> [**ground**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ground) (v): Prohibit or prevent (a pilot or an aircraft) from flying. *‘a bitter wind blew from the north-east and the bombers were grounded’*

It's kind of an *idiomatic* expression that started in the 1930s as a punishment for pilots who committed some kind of infraction, to take away their flying privileges -- i.e. to *keep them on the ground*.

Comment: What kind of dictionary do you read, the first definition of ground is that?

Comment: See the link in the answer. Oxford English living dictionary.

Comment: @马化腾 There are, of course, many other definitions of "ground" as a verb, many slightly idiomatic and particular to a field.  Each dictionary seems to give a different set of answers, so I'm not surprised you are confused.